# Querying the Download History list in Firefox 29+

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, firefox-addon

I need to generate the history list of download files for an extension compatible with Firefox 29.  [Downloads.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm) only retrieves the download list for the active session. I need to get the list of the all downloaded files. I mean the ones that was downloaded say, 2 weeks ago.

How can I get the download history for Firefox 29?

Comment: The implementation of the download history is here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/downloads/content/allDownloadsViewOverlay.js

Comment: Thanks. Any code example please, I am new to Firefox. I am not asking for UI. I just want to get the file names of history downloads as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query the `Places` database.

```js
var sqlstr = "SELECT title FROM moz_places WHERE id IN (SELECT place_id FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE visit_type = 7)"
var conn = PlacesUtils.history.QueryInterface(Ci.nsPIPlacesDatabase).DBConnection;
var stmt = conn.createAsyncStatement(sqlstr);

stmt.executeAsync({
  _filenames: [],
  handleResult: function(aResultSet){
    let row;
    while((row = aResultSet.getNextRow())){
      this._filenames.push(row.getResultByIndex(0));
    }
  },
  handleError: function(aError){
  },
  handleCompletion: function(aReason){
    console.log(this._filenames.join(","))
  }
});
```

That mysterious 7 is the value of `Ci.nsINavHistoryService.TRANSITION_DOWNLOAD`.

Comment: Thanks paa. You seem to forget `var stmt = conn.createAsyncStatement(sqstr);`. It works great.

Comment: Where can I find the database file so I can inspect it? And how can I create nsiDownload objects by these row results to use Downloads API?